# iPhone Dev: Playing back a flash animation

Tags: iphone, animation, multimedia

I am building a simple application that has a few buttons that when clicked play a video.

Right now I have those videos as flash files. For my first attempt I tried converting them to .mov and used the MediaPlayer framework. The video/are very poor and when you double click the video controls pop up.

Im not sure what the best way to do this is. Is the MediaPlayer the wrong route? Is there a better way?

Here is an example of another app that is doing exactly what I need. Crazy Eye: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01R9N8ILPvk

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Media Player framework shouldn't impact the quality of your videos, that's something that should be addressed by the type of encoding options you specify when you convert the videos.

Since there is no flash on the iPhone, the only option you have is to convert them to an iPhone friendly format, namely:

"Supported Formats
This class supports any movie or audio files that already play correctly on an iPod or iPhone. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)"

The Media Player framework is definitely the way you should go.

If you don't want the controls to appear you can set the movieControlMode property on your MPMovieController class.

```
@property (nonatomic) MPMovieControlMode movieControlMode
```

Comment: Great answer! Answered everything! Thanks a lot!